# unable to get data from js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

this is the code which fetch data from database AJAX i ha dcheck the table names and syntax but there is some problem i am unable to get the data .

file name :: ajax_check_uname.php

```
<?php


    $dbhandle = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
    mysql_select_db('db_new', $dbhandle) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

    if(isset($_POST['uname']))//If a name has been submitted 
    {
    $uname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);//Some clean up :)

    $check_for_uname = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM `db_new`.`operators` WHERE uname='$uname'");
    //Query to check if uname is available or not 

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_for_uname))
    {
    echo '1';//If there is a  record match in the Database - Not Available
    }
    else
    {
    echo '0';//No Record Found - uname is available 
    }

    }

    mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

this is the script code where i will call to the above file for data verification.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()    //When the dom is ready 
    {
    $("#uname").change(function() 
    { //if theres a change in the uname textbox

    var uname = $("#uname").val();    //Get the value in the uname textbox
    //var re = ^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)\$;
    if(uname) //if the length greater than 5 characters
    {
    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/ahs/images/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
    //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

    $.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/abc/app/views/ControlPanelViews/forms/ajax_check_uname.php",  //file name
        data: "uname="+ uname,  //data
        //data: {uname: value},
        success: function(server_response){  

       $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

        if(server_response == '0')  //if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
        { 
        $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/abc/images/available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
        //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
        }  
        else  if(server_response == '1')    //if it returns "1"
        {  
         $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/abc/images/not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
        }   
       });
       } 
      }); 
    }

    else
    {

    $("#availability_status").html('<label></label>');
    //if in case the uname is less than or equal 6 characters only 
    }


    return false;
    });

    });
</script>
```

the below is the HTML form code for displaying the data.

HTML FORM :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="name" type="text">
<span id="availability_status"></span>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()    //When the dom is ready 
    {
    $("#uname").change(function() 
    { //if theres a change in the uname textbox

    var uname = $("#uname").val();    //Get the value in the uname textbox
    //var re = ^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)\$;
    if(uname) //if the length greater than 5 characters
    {
    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/ahs/images/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
    //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

    $.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/abc/app/views/ControlPanelViews/forms/ajax_check_uname.php",  //file name
        data: {uname: uname},  //data
        success: function(server_response){  

       $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

        if(server_response == '0')  //if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
        { 
        $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/abc/images/available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>  ');
        //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
        }  
        else  if(server_response == '1')    //if it returns "1"
        {  
         $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/abc/images/not_available.png" align="absmiddle"> <font color="red">Not Available </font>');
        }   
       });
       } 
      }); 
    }

    else
    {

    $("#availability_status").html('<label></label>');
    //if in case the uname is less than or equal 6 characters only 
    }


    return false;
    });

    });
</script>
```